# How can I substitute double backslashes for single backslashes?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Example:

```
example <- "\\begin"
example <- gsub(pattern = "\\\\", replacement = "\\", example)
```

I know the backslashes need to be escaped, which is why they're duplicated in the gsub function. But this code returns the string "begin" devoid of any backslashes. I've also tried

```
example <- "\\begin"
example <- gsub(pattern = "\\", replacement = "\", example, fixed = TRUE)
```

But RStudio (and apparently StackOverflow!) really doesn't like that--it treats "" like an open quotation mark followed by an escaped close quotation mark, rather than treating it as a string of a single backslash.

How can I do this? For better context, I have a .txt file of .tex code (except that every backslash is duplicated) that I am trying to turn into a .tex file within an Rmd document.

I'd be happy to use an implementation using stringr, if that makes things easier.

Comment: `example` has single backslash already. Run `cat(example)` to see the actual string.

Comment: Gah! This is just my failed attempt at making a reproducible example. In reality I’m importing from a .txt file, and I can see from opening that file that there are two backslashes.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the real data, and manually enter the string you really want.

Answer (score 0):

> `example` has single backslash already. Run `cat(example)` to see the actual string.

[Credit: Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311523/how-can-i-substitute-double-backslashes-for-single-backslashes#comment117232881_66311523)